# Use a shell variable with Awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have this:

```
if [[ $1 = "-c" ]] && [[ $2 =~ ^[a-z A-Z]+$ ]]
then
awk -v var="$2" '{print $2}' something.txt
fi
```

What I want is with a comand like `-c abc` to show the lines in something.txt that include `abc`.

Comment: Why not just use [`grep`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137614/135943)?  That's the tool for the job.  Simple is usually better.

Answer (score 2):

Use grep:

```
grep abc something.txt
```

---

Also note that using `$2` in the *shell* refers to the second argument (as you seem to know), but in `awk` it is different.  Your question seems to show a misunderstanding of this so I'll clarify it.

The shell requires the `$` to refer to the value of a variable.  So you refer to a variable named `myvar` by writing `$myvar`.

In `awk` to refer to a variable named `myvar` you just use its name—`myvar`.  To refer to a literal string containing the letters m-y-v-a-r, you type `"myvar"`.

The `$` in `awk` is to refer to the *field* with a specific *number*.  So `$2` refers to the second field of the current line of the file.  Or if you set `myvar = "4"`, then `$myvar` refers to the *fourth* field of the file.

For just printing all lines of a file that match a given pattern, use `grep`—that's what it's designed for.

Answer (score 2):

just as a disclaimer, awk isn't the right tool for this job — i'm assuming your actual use case is more complex and justified, so thanks for distilling it!

This specific issuse looks like it comes down to two things, variable "expansion" and passing args from bash to awk.

#### awk variables and `$`

once you prefix a awk variable with `$`, it will immediately make that a reference to a field: which is weird if you're used to the shell, php, or perl.

so an input like this

```
thing alive
cat yes
lamp no
```

piped through `awk 'BEGIN{alive=2}{print $alive}'` will yield

```
alive
yes
no
```

while `awk 'BEGIN{alive=2}{print alive}'` would yield

```
2
2
2
```

When mixing awk with bash, things get a little strange; hopefully that helps with the first part.

#### passing args from bash to awk

if you're set on using awk, and setting awk vars in the bash command, you're probably looking for this:

```
if [[ $1 = "-c" ]] && [[ $2 =~ ^[a-z A-Z]+$ ]]
then
    awk -v var="$2" 'index($0, var)' something.txt
fi
```

note: the `index($0, var)` is short for `if (index($0, var)) { print $0 }`

---

admittedly, it's not a "pretty" solution, but that gets back to awk being the wrong tool for the job.  For a full awk solution check out [`ARGV` and `ARGC`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html)

Comment: yes maybe awk its not the 'cool' solution! anyway that was helpfull thanks !

Comment: I don't think they want the `index`, but the whole line. But I agree that `grep` is much simpler.

Comment: that's correct  @Sparhawk. That won't print the index,  it will print the whole line; playing to some of awk's shortcut friendliness — It's about as close as you'll get to a substring matcher in awk

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I misread the code. +1